# how to find the characters before and after a word in a string in php

Tags: php, string

Please forgive me if this question is too easy. But, I am very new to coding. Basically this is what I want:-

Consider a String str1 like "I need some help, please help me find the solution."

Now I have another string str2 "need some help".

All I want is check whether the string str2 is present in str1. After that, i need the characters before and after the string str2 in str1 i.e. in this case "space" and "comma". 
Can someone please tell me how can i do it in php?

Comment: Look at the php functions like `strstr`, `strpos` and `substring`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are **2 examples** of how you can *extract* the desired characters of your string

```
$str = "I need some help, please help me find the solution.";

$search = "need some help";

list( $start, $end ) = explode($search, $str);

//Method 1: use substr to extract the one character at beginning or end
$s1 = substr($start, -1, 1);
$e1 = substr($end, 0, 1);
var_dump($s1); //outputs whitespace
var_dump($e1); //outputs comma

//Method 2: use index on string to get character
$s2 = $start[count($start)];
$e2 = $end[0]; 
var_dump($s2); //outputs whitespace
var_dump($e2); //outputs comma
```